How to name Environment variable in GCC under configuration/variables?
We've noticed that when creating environment variables in GCC or in config.properties files, some variales have "." for example "apd.service.runtimeApiCacheSize" and some have "_" (underscores) for example "SUITE_BC_PRODUCT_URL". What's difference between the two? Which of the two should we use and when?
Both of them seem to be working but both have different naming standards as per documentation.

Variables are available to replace placeholders in various configuration files within the InsuranceSuite and xEngage implementations.  Inside the InsuranceSuite applications, use of variables is constrained by the various Namespaces that are enabled.  For example, variables can replace content in config.xml, but not in some random Gosu class.  The naming requirements for variables are documented in the product documentation here (requires login).  Convention for Variables is to use UpperCase and Underscores, but the allowed values (other than the NAMESPACE_ portion) are only constrained by the naming standards.
Runtime properties are more flexible and can be referenced in code as desired, but don't replace values at deployment like Variables do.  Their naming doesn't require the Namespace content and is documented at the same link.  Runtime properties are more commonly named using period separators but again, the naming is only constrained by the character requirements documented.
